# Necessary properties for a domain set to allow unique derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Under which circumstances does a set $X\subseteq{\bf R}^n$ has the property that for all $f:X\rightarrow{\bf R}^m$ and $A,A'\in{\bf R}^{n\times m}$ with $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0,x\in X}\frac{f(x)-f(0)-A(x)}{\|x\|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0,x\in X}\frac{f(x)-f(0)-A'(x)}{\|x\|}=0$$ we have $A=A'$, i.e. the structure of the domain allows to extend the definition of derivatives to non-interiour points (here I considered only $0$) in a way that makes sense (forces uniqueness).

I guess we can w.l.o.g. assume $m=1$ here...

Edit: I just saw that we don't need to consider any functions $f$, it suffices to just state $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0,x\in X}\frac{A(x)}{\|x\|}=0$$ implies $A=0$.

Some examples: It's enough if $X$ lies dense around $0$, i.e. $0$ lies in the ineriour of the closure of $X$.  Or if $v_0,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ are linerarly independent vectors and $X=\cup_{i<n} {\bf R}v_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Derivatives are defined locally. It's one of their most important properties. If you look at the definition of the derivative, you need this difference quotient to exist for $x$ very near $0$ (or wherever you are taking the derivative). The definition is usually stated as

$$0=\lim_{|h|\to 0}\dfrac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah|}{|h|}$$
What we need implicitly here is that $f(x+h)$ is defined for $h$ sufficiently small. What this means is that the point where you're taking the derivative $x$ must have some convex neighborhood in your domain set $X$ (or even a star-shaped neighborhood of $x$ would work, I think). Once you have this property, the derivative is well-defined and uniqueness is just an algebraic consequence of the definitions.

So, as long as the point you're taking the derivative at has a convex neighborhood, the derivative is unique. In particular, wherever the derivative is defined on $X$, it must be unique. If the derivative is defined on all $x\in X$, then we need $X$ itself to be open, as this allows every point to have a convex neighborhood. I'm not sure if there's a larger class of sets that this is true (you could define the derivative on a closed set $X$, but this amounts to just extending to a larger open set and taking a restriction).

Comment: It clearly suffices that $0$ lies in the interior of $X$.  Usually one assumes that also in the definition of the differential, but for example in ${\bf R}$ one sometimes talks about one-sided limits to define $f'$ on the boundary of $[a,b]$ when $f$ is also defined on $[a,b]$.  I just wondered whether there is some generalization to this, when are we allowed to define differentials for non-interior points without giving up on uniqueness of the differential...

Comment: Yes, there are one sided limits in $\mathbb{R}$. If I recall correctly, the derivative at an endpoint is the one sided limit, so this is not really a derivative, but more of a "one-sided" derivative, and it is unique since limits in $\mathbb{R}$ are unique. In higher dimensions, derivatives at limit points are defined based on extensions. Necessity is still having a convex or star shaped neighborhood, since the uniqueness is then an algebraic property of the derivative, not analytic.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with derivatives at limit points are defined based on extensions?  And yes, in ${\bf R}$ the condition is exactly that $0$ as an limit point of $X$ but in higher dimensions things are not so easy...

Comment: If $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed, then $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable on $X$ if there is an open set $Y\supset X$ and a differentiable function $\hat{f}:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\hat{f}|_X=f$. You could equivalently use a directional derivative on the limit points, but uniqueness here is again a result of algebra. Wherever it is defined, it must be unique.

Comment: Ah, that's nice.  This obviously also coincides with the definition via one-sided limits on endpoints of intervalls in ${\bf R}$.  I totally believe that this definition is much more practical, I just got somehow curious about the geometric properties of sets necessary for my condition even if it has nothing practical to do with differentiation (OK, I should edit the tags then)...

Comment: Yes. Moreover, in your edit, you correctly state that the result comes down to showing that $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{|A(x)|}{|x|}=0$ implies $A=0$. But this is true: take $t\to 0, t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{|A(x)|}{|x|}=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{|A(tx)|}{|tx|}=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{t|A(x)|}{t|x|}=\dfrac{|A(x)|}{|x|}=0$ for arbitrary $x\in X$. So $A=0$.

Comment: Yes, but here you assume that the limits $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|A(tx)\|}{\|tx\|}$ exist in the sense that there are enough points around $0$ in the direction of $x$, but what if for example $X={\bf R}^2\setminus {\bf R}$, then the property still holds but the limit in the direction of $1$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes. Again, there's no requirement that that limit exist. But if that limit doesn't exist, then the derivative doesn't exist. If $A_1,A_2$ are derivatives of $f$, then $A=A_1-A_2$, and we have $|Ax|\leq |f(x)-f(0)-A_1x|+|f(x)-f(0)-A_2x|$. Divide both sides by $|x|$ and take the limit as $x\to 0$. If the limit of the RHS exists, then the squeeze theorem forces the limit on the LHS to exist and be equal to 0 and the argument follows. If the limit of the LHS doesn't exist, then the limit of the RHS must not exist either, meaning that we could not have $A_1,A_2$, so there is no derivative.

Comment: OK, maybe I should change the title also?  It was derivatives which brought me to this idea, but I find it now an interesting question on its own, still I think the title is not completely misleading since it brings some intuition.  Also, Fremlin talks in his second book on measure theory about derivatives relative to its domain and he uses exactly the approach I outlined (he's also not asking for uniqueness, so e.g. any function would be differentiable relative to its domain on an isolated point with arbitrary derivative).

Comment: I edited the question again and tried to make it more clear that I consider also the cases where derivatives would not be defined in a classical sense...

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha>0$ and $0\le i<n$ let $$C_{\alpha,i}:=\{(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}):x_i\neq 0,(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{n-1})/x_i\in B_\alpha(0)\},$$ i.e. the double cone with radius $\alpha$ extending along the $i$th axis.  Then a set $X$ fulfills our premise if there exists $\alpha$ such that $X\cap B_\epsilon\cap C_{\alpha,i}\neq\emptyset$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and $0\le i<n$.